# How to convert timestamp to string in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: date-format, pentaho

I have a timestamp field in my input table like this: `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:dd`,  I want  output sting like this: `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: what format are you outputting to?

Comment: output should be string like as YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the select values step. Convert the data type to a string and specify the mask:

yyyyMMdd

Note the mask is a java simpleDateFormat and you can google that for more details. It is case SENSITIVE.

The mask in PDI is only used for 3 things:

1. Converting from the real data type to a string
2. Display purposes when previewing data
3. Any other time you convert to "text" i.e. CSV output, or bulk loaders.

If you are sending it to a target database as a timestamp then it will be whatever that target database uses as default format.